# AJAX request to server to find customer session in OpenCart 2

Tags: php, ajax, session, opencart2.x

Using Opencart 2.0.x When a customer visits the site, they are always greeted with a login page. If they successfully logged in but closed the browser"tab" not the browser iself, they are still technically logged in. When they return they are greeted with the login page again as that is what is in the index.php file in the root folder, if they attempt to log in, it wont redirect them. I was curious how to Request an AJAX call to the server to find a valid customer session. Or to check the browser if a `seessionid` is current so that it will automatically redirect to the actual site. Mind you that the main site is in the subdirectory `/login`, the file I am working with is in the root folder, so attempting to use

```
if(isset($_SESSION["ccustomer_id"])) { 
  /*redirect to main site*/ 
} else { 
  /*let user login*/ 
}
```

doesnt seem to work.Here is the rest of my code from the index.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'login/index.php?route=account/loginajax',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('input[type=\'text\'], input[type=\'password\']'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-cart').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-cart').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            if (json['error']) {
                $('.error').after('<div class="alert alert-danger has-error">' + json['error'] + '</div>');
            }
            if (json['success']) {
                $('.error').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '</div>');
                window.location = "http://www.mbdtesting.com/login/index.php?     route=account/account";
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You could create an ajax call on initial page load that sends a request to check if `$_SESSION["ccustomer_id"]` is set, and returns a similar response to your current ajax check.

Comment: You shouldn't use AJAX for this. You should do it directly in your home page's controller, and redirect immediately.